# JavaScript execution order of setTimeout() callbacks with different delays

Tags: javascript, settimeout

If multiple callbacks are registered at the same time, is it guaranteed that the first callback to be called will be the one with the least delay?

Consider the following code:

```
function foo(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, i);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    foo(i);
}
```

Is this code guaranteed to output 1-1000 in order?

---

Please note: This question is **not** about using **equal** delays. It has been established that multiple setTimeout() calls with equal delays are **not** guaranteed to execute in order.

Comment: Yes, when the delay increments that way, it is guaranteed that the callbacks will be fired in order, however it's not guaranteed that the timer will be accurate.

Comment: May I ask for the reference that "multiple setTimeout() calls with equal delays are not guaranteed to execute in order"? Coz this at least seems conflicting with the HTML spec. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53244931/2160440  Not sure about server side implementation though.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes!!

```js
function foo(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, i);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    foo(i);
}
```

Explanation :

As you are Calling `setTimeout` it will execute independently doesn't matter how much `setTimeout` are running or will run,So its dependent on time you call and timing you set.Hope you get this.

Answer (score 0):

I know many of the people have already answered this question. But, most of the people don't know exactly how the event loop works. Even I got it recently. So, I thought it would be helpful to all whoever gets to this post.

`setTimeout()` function works in accordance with the event callback and render queue. Rendering queue is the reason why it is not guaranteed that your callback would execute after the exact timeout. There are concepts like

1. call stack,
2. web apis and
3. callback queue

You have this below function called multiple times,

```
function foo(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, i);
}
```

so the flow would be something like, each call to `foo(i)` would first go to call stack. Once the call stack reaches to its top (when loop is over), one by one the web api(browser specific)would handle the poped out function from the stack and then it moves to the callback queue when the timeout has reached. Depending on the availability that is, if rendering is not happening, the callback gets executed.

Inside the callback queue the functions are lined up in the order of calling.

So, the order is guaranteed.

A better place to understand the event queue is the below article.

[Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop?](http://www.youtube.com/embed/8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: "the functions are lined up in the order of calling" This is apparently only true for callbacks registered using setTimeout with unequal delays, because if you use equal delays, there's no guarantee of callback execution order.

Comment: @Richard if you use equal delays, the order would be considered from the stack. LIFO